# React Native useContext results are undefined

Tags: react-native

I am trying to useContext provider in my midiMonitor function. The midi monitor function is a helper function. The issue is that the context results as undefined because it's not inside the profile context. I am trying to figure out how to give the midiMonitor access to the profileContext. I know it can be done if I import the helper function inside the home component however I don't want to import it in the home component because it has nothing the do with the home component.

Is there another way I can use the midiMonitor helper function and have access to the contents of the profileContext

```
const App = () => {

    midiMonitor()

    return(
        <ProfileProvider>
            <Home />
        </ProfileProvider>
    )
}

const Home = () => {
    // some functions that have access to the Profile Provider
    const {profileName} = useContext(ProfileContext)

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>{profileName}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const midiMonitor = () => {
    const {profileName} = useContext(ProfileContext)

    if (profileName === 'default'){
        // results are undefined. I know why but do not want to 
        //import in into the Home component as it has nothing to do with the home component
        console.log('you are using default midi profile')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been easier if you could "ProfileContext" and "ProfileProvider". Here is an example of the same. Hope this helps.

```js
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const ProfileContext = createContext();

function Component1() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("Jesse Hall");

  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider value={user}>
      <h1>{`Hello ${user}!`}</h1>
      <Component2 user={user} />
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Component2() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component 2</h1>
      <Component3 />
    </>
  );
}

function Component3() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component 3</h1>
      <Component4 />
    </>
  );
}

function Component4() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component 4</h1>
      <Component5 />
    </>
  );
}

function Component5() {
  const user = useContext(ProfileContext);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component 5</h1>
      <h2>{`Hello ${user} again!`}</h2>
    </>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Component1 />);
```